Three-phase controlled rectifier power reversal issue in MATLAB Simulink
I have built a fully controlled three-phase rectifier in MATLAB Simulink. Now according to theory for RL load as I increase firing angle from 90 deg to 180 deg, the output voltage should become more and more negative, hence showing power reversal. But this thing is not happening in my simulation. I have tried my firing angle sequences, but nothing seems to work. Please help me out in this.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should add a current source in your load to make your 3-phase "converter" ... "reversible" (until a certain point).

This is a "non-autonomous" converter ... Don't know the right word in English ... One must add a "powering" source in the load as a "current" source.

The voltage can be "negative" ... only in the case of a "current source" in the load.
To say it in other words, the current must be "constant" across the load (this occurs when the inductor is "large".
According to load = "constant current" ... we can make these simulations.
Made with microcap v12.
Here are examples of two cases. Delayed pulses for 1 and 9 ms.
NB: you can't go until 10 ms, because of the "guard" angle necessary (= ~ 1 ms).
Case: 1 ms delay, positive voltage across the "load"

Case: 9 ms delay, negative voltage across the "load"


I regards of my simulation, what can be the mistake?

Add a current source in the load. Don't own MATLAB.
